# show custom value from frontend form in a post (custom post type)

Tags: custom-post-types, forms

I am using a frontend form to create posts in a custom post type (Everything is working fine excepts custom fields). I tried for hours to figure out, how i can show custom field value from the form in the post.

this is how i put the field values in the post.

```
    add_filter('quform_post_process_1', function (array $result, Quform_Form $form) {    
    $title = $form->getValue('quform_1_22');    
    $content = $form->getValue('quform_1_23'); 
    $add = $form->getValue('quform_1_24');

    $post = array(
        'post_title' => $title,
        'post_content' => $content,
        'post_type' => 'events',
        'post_status' => 'publish',
        'post_custom_field' => $add // this is the custom field which is not working
    );

    wp_insert_post($post);

    return $result;
}, 10, 2);
```

When i try to show a custom field like 'post_custom_field' its not working.

This code is within the archive.php for my custom post type

```
        <?php while ( have_posts() ) : ?>
            <?php the_post(); ?>
            <?php
                the_content();
                echo get_post_field('post_custom_field');
            ?>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Refer to [the parameters section in the documentation for `wp_insert_post`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/wp_insert_post/#parameters).

Custom fields (meta data) must be passed in the form of a key/value array with the parameter name `'meta_input'`.

Change

```
'post_custom_field' => $add
```

to

```
'meta_input' => array( 'post_custom_field' => $add )
```

To show the value, use the [`get_post_meta`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/get_post_meta/) function. `get_post_field` is only for the native fields in the `posts` table, not for custom meta data.

```
echo get_post_meta( get_the_ID(), 'post_custom_field', true );
```